# Error 500 (Internal Server Error) in API Laravel 5.8 and Angular 7

Tags: angular, laravel, api

I am running a project on Angular 7 and Laravel 5.8. When i post login form angular form to API Laravel I get error 500 (Internal Server Error) in console .... why?

I tried running the Application on local system, it works perfectly. But when I took it to online serve, the problem started.
Note: Backend API is working perfectly with POSTMAN.

My CORS.php in Laravel is:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
        return $next($request);
    }
```

kernel

```
    protected $middleware = [

        \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [

        'CORS' => \App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class,
    ];
```

route

```
Route::post('login', 'UserController@login');
```

login.service

```
export class SandboxUserService {

  private API_URL= environment.apiUrl;

  login(data) {
    return this.http.post(this.API_URL + '/login', data)
  }
```

login.component.ts

```
 onSubmit() {
    this.SandboxUser.login(this.form).subscribe(
      data => this.handleResponse(data),
       error => this.handleError(error)
    );
  }
  handleResponse(data) {
     this.notify.success('Done, you have successfully logged in.', {timeout:2000, position: "rightTop"})

    this.Token.handle(data.access_token);
    this.Auth.changeAuthStatus(true);
    // this.router.navigateByUrl('/admindashboard');
    if(this.form.id == 1){
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/admindashboard');
   }
   else
   {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/userdashboard');
   }
```

After login, I expect it to redirect me to the dashboard. But it did not respond. So when I inspect, I found this:

> Error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: `500` is a very generic error which occurs when there is some error on server side, can you show us the response which you get in your browser network tab

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://sandbox.cloudinteractiveplatforms.com/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://sandboxbackend.cloudinteractiveplatforms.com/api/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Can you show us the value of `environment.apiUrl`

Comment: apiUrl:   'http://sandboxbackend.cloudinteractiveplatforms.com/api',

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your URL, your API is running on **HTTPS** connection but you are trying to access it wihout HTTPS. That's why your request is being blocked and treated as insecure.

Try to change your URL from:

```
example.com/api/login
```

to

```
https://example.com/api/login
```

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sandboxbackend.cloudinteractiveplatforms.com/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Comment: This issue is related to CORS

Comment: How do I do that

Answer (score -1):

Have do you import Sandbox... class properly. In this case I prefer create a new module.
check this way

Comment: How do you mean

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP question if you need extra information, you can ask it in comments